# mod_rewrite to match files that are not images

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rules

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Where every request to the wp-content/uploads its handled by dl-file.php in order to check if user its logged in.

I need to still have that functionality but grant free access to images (png|jpg|gif|jpeg)
Im a bit lost i dont know how to modify the rewrite rule to check any file that its no an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before the rule that rewrites to dl-file.php you could insert more specific rules for images:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads/.*\.png)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads/.*\.jpg)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads/.*\.gif)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Each of the three rules has the same structure, I'll explain the first one:
match anything in uploads that ends in **.png**
with the brackets you save the whole path into a variable $1.

the right hand side of the rule gives this variable, so if you look
at one specific url this boils down to:

```
Rewrite wp-content/uploads/some.png wp-content/uploads/some.png [L]
```

the L at the end tells the rewrite engine that this is the last rule to apply.
so if it matches, the rewriting process ends here, your png-image is served.

Comment: The literal `.` before the extension should be escaped. You could condense the image regex into one line with `^(wp-content/uploads/.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif))$` as the regex.

Comment: thanks!  i did the escaping, but i'm keeping the three lines. I think that's easier to read for a beginner

Comment: Hi guys i discover a problem with this regex. If i type http://xxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/ it takes me to the dl-file.php and i dont need that because it brakes other functionality. I just need that only files that are not images goes to dl-file.php. Hope you can help me out